# Return rows in a Pandas dataframe by matching the nth digit of an integer?

Tags: python, pandas, integer, wildcard, python-3.7

I have a Pandas DataFrame. One integer column 'LOADCASE_ID' contains values of a fixed length, say 7 digits. I want to return rows where the nth digit matches a specific value.

E.g.

```py
d = {'X_VAL': [1.2, 0.2, 1.4, 2.3, 0.25 ], 
     'LOADCASE_ID': [1100123, 1200456, 1300345, 2134324, 2345300]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Gives...

```py
    X_VAL   LOADCASE_ID
0   1.20    1100123
1   0.20    1200456
2   1.40    1300345
3   2.30    2134324
4   0.25    2345300
```

I want something like...

```py
df.loc[df['SUBCASE'] == ?3?????]
```

to return...

```py
    X_VAL   LOADCASE_ID
2   1.40    1300345
4   0.25    2345300
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use panda's `str` accessor to slice the column on a specific index, and perform boolean indexing with the result:

```
df[df.LOADCASE_ID.astype(str).str[1].eq('3')]

    X_VAL  LOADCASE_ID
2   1.40      1300345
4   0.25      2345300
```